# repeat result multiple times in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table having id and no field, what I really want is the result raw will be repeated no filed times, if the no field is 2 then that raw must be repeated twice in result.
this is my sample table structure:

```
     id  no   
     1   3
     2   2
     3   1
```

now I need to get a result like:

```
1  3
1  3 
1  3
2  2
2  2
3  1
```

I tried to write mysql query to get the result like above, but failed.

Answer (score 4):

You need a table of numbers to accomplish this.  For just three values, this is easy:

```
select t.id, t.no
from t join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3
     ) n
     on t.no <= n.no;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query must do what you want to achieve:

```
select t.id, t.no from  test t cross join  test y where t.id>=y.id
```

Answer (score 0):

not completely solve your problem, but this one can help

```
set @i=0;

select 
    test_table.*
from 
     test_table
join 
    (select
         @i:=@i+1 as i
     from 
         any_table_with_number_of_rows_greater_than_max_no_of_test_table
     where 
         @i < (select max(no) from test_table)) tmp on no >= i
order by
     id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :
This is on SQL Server. I checked online and see that CTEs work on MySQL too. Just couldn't get them to work on SQLFiddle**

Try this, remove unwanted columns

```
create table #temp (id int, no int)

insert into #temp values (1, 2),(2, 3),(3, 5)

select * from #temp

;with cte as
    (
        select id, no, no-1 nom from #temp
        union all
        select c.id, c.no, c.nom-1 from cte c inner join #temp t on t.id = c.id and c.nom < t.no and c.nom > 0
    )

select * from cte order by 1

drop table #temp
```